# .Net Core Libery add new class No Items Found

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2015

Recentily on my project is unable to add a new class, When I try to add a new class the template list is empty, you have just the message "No Items found" and the add button is disable.

I using Visual Studio 2015, I have tried to create a new Core class libery project, re-install the templates, restore the visual studio and still the same erro.

Answer (score 0):

after a long time traing to fix... I re-install everthing, now it's ok.